# Not able to access twitter after a lot of try

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I work on windows 7 and i am trying to access twitter using tweepy and even twitter1.14.2-python.But i am not able crack it. Help needed.

***TWEEPY***

```
import tweepy

OAUTH_TOKEN = "defined here"
OAUTH_SECRET = "defined here"
CONSUMER_KEY = "defined here"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "defined here"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)

api = API.GetUserTimeline(screen_name="yyy")
```

Error :  name 'API' is not defined

***TWITTER 1.14.2***

```
import twitter
from twitter import *

tw = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
tw.statuses.home_timeline()
tw.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name="yyy")
```

Error :  No module named OAuth

*Where i am going wrong ?*

Answer (score 2):

As there is no `GetUserTimeline` defined/declared in [tweepy.API](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper) class, so am asuming that you intend to try the `GetUserTimeline` method of [twitter.Api](http://inventwithpython.com/twitter.html#Api-GetUserTimeline) class.

The `API` is exposed via the `twitter.Api` class.

To create an instance of the `twitter.Api` class:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api()
```

To create an instance of the `twitter.Api` with login credentials.

```
>>> api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='consumer_key', 
          consumer_secret='consumer_secret', access_token_key='access_token', 
          access_token_secret='access_token_secret')
```

To fetch a single user's public status messages, where `user` is either a `Twitter "short name" or their user id`

```
>>> statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(user)
>>> print [s.text for s in statuses]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I have posted my answer and its working well and fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

***Finally i got the way out with tweepy***

```
import tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = 'Deliver here'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Deliver here'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'Deliver here'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'Deliver here'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET)
urapi = tweepy.API(auth)
me = urapi.me()
print me().name
print me().screen_name
print me.followers_count
for status in tweepy.Cursor(myapi.user_timeline,id="abby").items(2):
     print status.text+"/n"
```